# Run-Time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set - works once then won't work again

Tags: excel, vba

I get the error mentioned in the title every time I try to run my VBA code. Error is appearing on this line:

```
    Set Button_Top_Result = IE.document.getElementById_
    ("javascript:gx.evt.execEvt('EUSRACNAM.CLICK.0001',this);").href
```

Also did some research online and find this alternative code and tried it as well.

```
     For Each ele In IE.document.getElementsByTagName("a")
        If InStr(ele.href, "javascript:gx.evt.execEvt('EUSRACNAM.CLICK.0001',this);") > 0 Then IE.navigate_
        ele.href: Exit For
     Next
```

This line worked once, and now no longer works.

VBA Novice here, so this might be a simple solution but I am stumped - working on navigating through the company website and wrote line to click on hyperlink to navigate me to this next page. It worked the first time, and then won't work and spits out the above error.  Really stumped here, already did some digging online and can't figure out where my error is.

Here is the html part of the web page

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgJOo.png

```
'''Option Explicit

Sub GetMasterDetailKeyedDataTest2()

'The goal of this macro is to quickly and conveniently update BNA Depreciation by automating the steps necessary to complete the process.

    'Dimensions identfy things I will define later to use.
Dim name As String
Dim IE As InternetExplorerMedium
Dim store As String
Dim client As String
Dim URL As String
Dim username
Dim Password
Dim Button_Next
Dim Button_Login
Dim Button_OnDemandReporting
Dim Search_Bar
Dim Button_Mag_Glass
Dim Button_Top_Result As Action

'Line below bypasses login if user is already logged in
'On Error Resume Next

store = Workbooks("Learning").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2")
client = Workbooks("Learning").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2")

'Abbreviates Internet Explorer. Note I need the correct references enabled in tools in order to run a web query using this name.
    Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium

'Define URL
    URL = "Company website"

'make IE browser visible (False would allow IE to run in the background)
'Once program is working I will want to turn this off so that the user doesn't see the webbrowser.
    IE.Visible = True

'Navigate to Login page
    IE.navigate URL

'This loop prevents Excel from continuing the code
        Do While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4

            DoEvents
        Loop

'These next four steps navigate through the login
        Set username = IE.document.getElementById("username") 'id of the username control (HTML Control)
        username.Value = "username"

        Set Button_Next = IE.document.getElementById("next") 'id of the button control (HTML Control)
        Button_Next.Click

        Set Password = IE.document.getElementById("password") 'id of the password control (HTML Control)
        Password.Value = "password"

        Set Button_Login = IE.document.getElementById("submit") 'id of the button control (HTML Control)
        Button_Login.Click

        Do While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4

            DoEvents
        Loop

'Connects to OnDemand Reporting
        Set Button_OnDemandReporting = IE.document.getElementById("IMAGE1_0004")
        Button_OnDemandReporting.Click

        Do While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4

            DoEvents
        Loop

        Set Search_Bar = IE.document.getElementById("vNAME")
        Search_Bar.Value = Workbooks("Learning").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2")

        Set Button_Mag_Glass = IE.document.getElementById("IMAGE1")
        Button_Mag_Glass.Click

        Set Button_Top_Result = IE.document.getElementById("javascript:gx.evt.execEvt('EUSRACNAM.CLICK.0001',this);").href
        Button_Top_Result.Click         

    End Sub
'''
```

I expect the last step to navigate me to the next part of the web page, but instead I keep getting the above error.

Comment: Are you sure that is the ID ? because it doesn't look like a ID

Comment: It worked once, the .href on the end modifies it to accept href stmts. Apolgies if language isn't accurate. Only started learning this stuff a couple of days ago.

Comment: I think the `.href` will pull the href of that element if that element exists. But Looking at the ID, i don't think that's the correct one. I maybe Wrong in this, but it will be clear for everyone to understand if you can paste the HTML of that Element from Source code of Website.

Comment: <A href="javascript:gx.evt.execEvt('EUSRACNAM.CLICK.0001',this);">John doe</A> Is this what you mean?

Comment: Exactly, see this is a Href not an ID.

Comment: Ok, so what should I do to fix the error? the element doesn't have an id.

Comment: Is this `javascript:gx.evt.execEvt('EUSRACNAM.CLICK.0001',this);` always the same? I would identify the element either by its `.innerText` or by the order it appears in the collection of `<a></a>` elements. Or even by the ID of a possible `<div></div>` element that contains the anchor element you're interested in. Updating your question to include a bigger snippet of the HTML code would be really helpful.

Comment: It is always the same. I tested it by pulling up different clients and it still matched. Link to html code is in the post.